# transform-origin of a rotated element inside a rotated parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to append a div as a child of an other div without changing its position (from a user point of view).

The "futur" parent is rotated of -30° the element that will become a child is rotated of -30°.

how to compute the right (left, top) position of the futur child ?

I tried to cancel the rotation of the futur parent

```
transform:rotate(0°)
```

and do the same for the futur child

```
transform:rotate(60°)
```

but with a transform-origin set to the transform-origin of the futur parent that means

```
Left(futur child)-tranform-originx (parent)
top(futur child)-transform-originy (parent)
```

but it does not seem to run 
any idea ?

HTML :

```
<div id="futurParentFrame" style="z-index:1000;position:absolute;left:100px;top:100px;background-color:red;border:black 6px dashed;width:800px;height:500px;transform:rotate(-30deg)">
</div>
<div id="futurChildDiv" style="z-index:1002;position:absolute;left:493px;top:192px;background-color:gray;border-left:blue 4px dashed;border-right:blue 2px dashed;width:250px;height:150px;transform:rotate(30deg);"></div>
```

Comment: Since the posted code sample doesn't have a parent/child relation, I don't understand the question. Also, an image showing the _now_ and _expected_ output would help

Answer (score 0):

The math is somehow complex. I have tried to done it in the most simple way possible.

Click on the button to create the new child. The old one is semitransparent so that you can see them overlapping

```js
function createChild () {
    var parent = document.getElementById("futurParentFrame");
    var child = document.getElementById("futurChildDiv");

    var parentCoor = getCoor (parent);
    var childCoor = getCoor (child);
    
    var newChild = child.cloneNode(true);
    newChild.id = "newChild";
    newChild.style.transform = "rotate(60deg)";
    var r = Math.hypot (parentCoor.x - childCoor.x, parentCoor.y - childCoor.y);
    var alpha = -30 * Math.PI / 180;
    var relativeX = childCoor.x - parentCoor.x; 
    var relativeY = childCoor.y - parentCoor.y; 
    var rotatedX = relativeX * Math.cos(alpha) + relativeY * Math.sin(alpha); 
    var rotatedY = relativeX * -Math.sin(alpha) + relativeY * Math.cos(alpha); 
    var left =  (parentCoor.width * 0.5) - parentCoor.borderLeft - (childCoor.width * 0.5) + rotatedX;
    var top =  (parentCoor.height * 0.5) - parentCoor.borderTop - (childCoor.height * 0.5) + rotatedY;    
    newChild.style.left = left + "px";
    newChild.style.top = top + "px";
    parent.appendChild(newChild);
}

function getCoor (element) {
    var left = element.offsetLeft;
    var top = element.offsetTop;
    var width = element.offsetWidth;
    var height = element.offsetHeight;
    var centerX = left + width * 0.5; 
    var centerY = top + height * 0.5; 
    var borderLeft = parseInt (element.style.borderLeftWidth);
    var borderTop = parseInt (element.style.borderTopWidth);
    return {left: left, 
            top: top,
            width: width,
            height: height, 
            x: centerX, 
            y: centerY,
            borderLeft: borderLeft,
            borderTop: borderTop};
}
```

```css
#futurChildDiv {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="futurParentFrame" style="z-index:1000;position:absolute;left:100px;top:100px;background-color:red;border:black 6px dashed;width:800px;height:500px;transform:rotate(-30deg)">
</div>
<div id="futurChildDiv" style="z-index:1002;position:absolute;left:493px;top:192px;background-color:gray;border-left:blue 4px dashed;border-right:blue 2px dashed;width:250px;height:150px;transform:rotate(30deg);"></div>
<button onclick="createChild();">run</button>
```